# Switching to two different states in Jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Jquery function which does the Things as Shown below in Image

1.I have a div which lists all the products in one page and people who ever are interested 
  may choose either tick or cross.

2.On Clicking the cross in Image1 it will change the div as in image 2 (i.e) Not interested will be shown and tick will appear only in symbol

3.On Clicking the tick symbol in Image2 It should make the div as in Image 1 (i.e) I am interested will be shown and cross will appear only in symbol

[image]

I have created 4 Separate Images and written class as Below

```css
.CrossMe
    {
        background : url(CrossMe.gif) no-repeat;
        cursor     : pointer;
        float      : left;
        height     : 44px;
        width      : 51px;
    }

    .TickMe
    {
        background : url(TickMe.gif) no-repeat;
        cursor     : pointer;
        float      : left;
        height     : 44px;
        width      : 49px;
    }

    .NotInterested
    {
        background : url(NotInterested.gif) no-repeat;
        cursor     : pointer;
        float      : left;
        height     : 44px;
        width      : 241px;
    }

    .Interested
    {
        background : url(IamInterested.gif) no-repeat;
        cursor     : pointer;
        float      : left;
        height     : 44px;
        width      : 243px;
    }
```

and Jquery to change class as Below

```
$('document').ready(function(){             
        $('.CrossMe').click(function(){
            $(this).prev().attr('class', 'TickMe');             
            $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');

            $(this).prev().click(function(){
                $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
                $(this).toggleClass('Interested');
            });
        });

        $('.TickMe').click(function(){
            $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
            $(this).toggleClass('Interested');

            $(this).next().click(function(){
                $(this).next().attr('class', 'TickMe');
                $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');
            });
        });
    });
```

and HTML as Below

```
<pre>
<div class="Interested"></div>
<div class="CrossMe"></div>
</pre>
```

Now my code works for Only once after that it is working but not as i Expected.

Could some one help me in fixing this

Please don't use ID as I will be displaying more than one div's with products in them on the same page

Thanks in Advance

I have pasted The Whole HTML Code below

```
<pre>
       <style>
        .CrossMe
        {
            background : url(CrossMe.gif) no-repeat;
            cursor       :  pointer;
            float            : left;
            height       : 44px;
            width            : 51px;
        }

        .TickMe
        {
            background : url(TickMe.gif) no-repeat;
            cursor       :  pointer;
            float            : left;
            height       : 44px;
            width            : 49px;
        }

        .NotInterested
        {
            background : url(NotInterested.gif) no-repeat;
            cursor       :  pointer;
            float            : left;
            height       : 44px;
            width            : 241px;
        }

        .Interested
        {
            background : url(IamInterested.gif) no-repeat;
            cursor       :  pointer;
            float            : left;
            height       : 44px;
            width            : 243px;
        }

        .Button
        {
        cursor  :   pointer;
        }
        </style>
        <script>

        $('document').ready(function(){             
            $('.CrossMe').click(function(){
                    $(this).prev().attr('class', 'TickMe');             
                    $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');

                    $(this).prev().click(function(){
                        $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
                        $(this).toggleClass('Interested');
                    });
            });

            $('.TickMe').click(function(){
                    $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
                    $(this).toggleClass('Interested');

                    $(this).next().click(function(){
                        $(this).prev().attr('class', 'TickMe');
                        $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');
                    });
            });
        });     

        </script>

      <div class="Interested"></div>
      <div class="CrossMe"></div>
</pre>
```

Comment: I have pasted the whole code below the question

Comment: it appears to me that there is a typo in `<div class="CrossMe" onclick="NotInterested(this)">` and class must be `NotInterested` not  `CrossMe`, isn't it?

Comment: I guess you mean the Div Right. The first Div will be in such a state to show I am Interested and Cross me symbol as in Image1

Comment: Tickme.Gif - Tick Image Symbol, CrossMe.gif - Cross Image Symbol, Interested.gif - I am Interested Image, NotInterested.gif - I am Not Interested Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for not checked solution, but I'll try to improve if it won't work, try this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var $pre = $('pre');
    $pre.delegate('div.CrossMe', 'click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'TickMe') 
             .prev().attr('class', 'NotInterested');
    });

    $pre.delegate('div.TickMe', 'click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'CrossMe')
             .prev().attr('class', 'Interested');
    });
});
```

I use `var $pre = $('pre');` cause it is some sort of optimization. You need to attach a handler to `<pre>` DOM object 2 times. You can do it this way:

```
$('pre').someMethod();
$('pre').someMethod();
```

But why to call `jQuery` constructor two times to get eventually the same object? it is better to call it only once, save it to a variable and work with it further.

I frequently see smth like:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).methodcall();
    $(this).anotherMethodcall();
    $(this).yetAnotherMethodcall();
});
```

This is not a good approach

Comment: Would you mind if I ask why you are using the pre at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would solve your case, but it might be more compact to deal with these states more via CSS. I put together a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7336/ . I added some comments where you would define the images for each state, although I probably got the order wrong. You get the idea though.

Comment: ah, sorry - was responding while you edited the question. let me know if that helped anyway :)

Comment: Hey David Thanks a ton.I already tried this method.See I am Interested is shown the user should not switch back state on clicking I am interested.But as per the example you shown it is changing states at both the ends I mean on clicking both it is switching states but it should not be that way.On clicking the Symbol alone it should change the state

Answer (score 1):

Since the DOM objects are being manipulated per click, the click events need re-binding on run-time; you may try using the `.on()` method:

```
$('document').ready(function(){             
    $('body').on('click', '.CrossMe', function(){
        $(this).prev().attr('class', 'TickMe');             
        $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');

        $(this).prev().click(function(){
            $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
            $(this).toggleClass('Interested');
        });
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.TickMe', function(){
        $(this).next().attr('class', 'CrossMe');
        $(this).toggleClass('Interested');

        $(this).next().click(function(){
            $(this).next().attr('class', 'TickMe');
            $(this).toggleClass('NotInterested');
        });
    });
});
```

Not checked, but should work !!

Comment: I have Uploaded the file in this URL plz check it out http://filesave.me/file/21181/Original-html.html                                It is not working                                                            Dont forget to add jquery engine to this.Thank you

Comment: Ahh! sorry my firewall blocked the link, can You use jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a ton here is the link below

Answer (score 1):

**Use the below jQuery script:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){             
    $('.CrossMe').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('TickMe');
    var prevClass = $(this).prev().attr('class');
        if(prevClass=='Interested'){
        $(this).prev().removeClass('Interested').addClass('NotInterested');
        } 
        else{
        $(this).prev().removeClass('NotInterested').addClass('Interested');
        }
    });
    }); ​
```